# my universal link does not work and yet the deep link works

Tags: ionic3, ios-universal-links, deeplink

I need your help. I installed deeplink with universal link, but it does not work and yet I think I did the right thing by following this tutorial:

> https://blog.ionicframework.com/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps

Here is my config.xml file:

```
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-deeplinks" spec="1.0.17">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="aefinfo" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="www.aefinfo.fr" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
</plugin>
<engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.5" />
```

Here is my app.component.js:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, App ,Platform, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Deeplinks } from '@ionic-native/deeplinks';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  constructor( public appCtrl: App, public events: Events, private deeplinks: Deeplinks) {
    this.initializeApp();
    $('.show-backdrop').click(function(){
      this.myInput = ""
      this.recherches = []
    })
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.myInput = ""
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
      this.splashScreen.hide();

//deeplink commence par ici
      this.deeplinks.route({
     '/': {},
     '/depeche': {'depeche': true}
   }).subscribe((match) => {

      alert(JSON.stringify(match.$args.id));
   }, nomatch => {
     // nomatch.$link - the full link data
     alert(JSON.stringify(nomatch));

   });

     
    });
  }
```

Here is my apple-app-site-association file:

```js
   {
  "applinks": {
    "apps": ["BS753AW6QB.com.aefinfo.info"],
    "details": [
    {
      "appID": "BS753AW6QB.com.aefinfo.info",
      "paths": ["/depeche/*"]
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is an xcode capture for the association domain:
[image]

when I am in my site and I click on www.aefinfo.fr/depeche/563478, it does not open the application to me and yet I despatched in my universal link.

on the other hand when I click on the link: aefinfo: //www.aefinfo.fr/depeche/563478 it works.

My problem is the univsersal link that does not work.
Thanks for your help